# Name 'stopwords' is not defined but I already import the package

Tags: python, stop-words

I am trying to use stopwords, but I am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'stopwords' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```py
import nltk
import re
nltk.download('stopwords')
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Have the list of stopwords.

Comment: As the error says, `stopwords` is not defined in that code. Did you mean to import it?

Comment: Remember that you only need to download NLTK corpora once, so you don't keep that in your script, you just run that as a one-time Python command line action. Once you've downloaded it, you use `from nltk.corpus import stopwords`.

Comment: nowehere do you import anything named `stopwords`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
print(stops)
```